# How to change specific system entities on Crm 2011?

Tags: entity, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to change some system entities and I realize that on some system entities you cannot change anything.

For example, I can add fields and relationships on a "serviceactivity" bit it's not possible to change something in "service" or "site".

I really can't understand, why for example the "site" entity has about 20 fields which are predefined and are not used (on the form, by default) or can't even added to the form.

Is there any supported / unsupported way where i can change (add fields, relationships) to records from "site" entities?

I'm developing on Crm 2011 rollup 6.

Regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find any supported way to modify the Site entity as it appears to be one of the few that Microsoft has locked down, probably due to some internal limitations that prevent other functionality from breaking. I attempted to add the Site entity to an unmanaged solution, once I exported it I was able to modify the XML directly and reimport it. CRM however appears to ignore any changes that are made. With that said I'm thinking that going down the unsupported route would likely end up breaking something later on.